Two \footnotemark in one environment
Until now I haven't had any problems with \footnotemark because I have only used one. Now I need to use two in one environment but I get the same footnote count. How can I chance that?
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{6.5cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img1}
    \caption{Picture One\protect \footnotemark}\label{Pic1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}{5.75cm}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{img2}
    \caption{Picture Two\protect \footnotemark}
    \label{Pic2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two Pictures}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Source 1}
\footnotetext{Source 2}


Try \footref works like a \label you gve it a unique name.  \footref{myname}` etc..

It doesn't work. Do I need to use it instead of \footnotemark?

Yes, it needs a fairly recent distribution though. What class you using? Just add it to your minimal example and I will test as well.

In general though you should not add footnotes in captions, as they will appear in the table of contents as well, as this is not good practice.

You are right! I have just seen it. So what is the solution? I use a lot of pictures and I need to add the source of the pictures.

I personally add  at the end of the caption text caption(blah blah blah credit(source)).

@Lagrange: How about this? Using \footenotetext's optional argument to force the numbering. You'll also see me use the optional argument of \caption to avoid \footnotemarks ending up in the LoF.

Thanks! But since I have two \footnotemarks, I get the same footnote number, meaning it does not count automatically. Do I have to do it manually?

The advice to use the argument of \caption was very good! Thank you!

@Lagrange: This is the output I get when I compile the minimal example (with \usepackage[paperheight=200pt]{geometry} added to the preamble). Note that \footnotemark produces different numbers in the figure, and \footnotetext[1]{<text>} forces the numbering of the first footnote text to be 1. In short, I don't see what you're stating.

Thank you very much for your comment! In my document I have already 429 footnotes. When I follow your example, I get for both pictures the same footnote number, in my case 430. So I don't get 430 and 431 but 430 and 430. In this case I would have to insert the numbers manually, meaning \footnotetext[430]{<text>} and \footnotetext[431]{<text>} which is 'dangerous' if I add or delete footnote before this section.
